# SAS Help on Libname Statement, how to use macro variable on Libname Statement?

Tags: sas

I have the below Libname statement. I don't want to hardcode the year 2022 in the libname statement, I want to pass that as macro variable. i.e., %let year = 2022. How can I use this macro variable on libname statement?

```
libname LIB1 'aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/2022/fff';
```

I'd like to replace 2022 as a macro variable value.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve macro variables inside quotes, they (generally) need to be within double-quotes.

```
%LET YEAR = 2022 ;
libname lib1 "aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/&YEAR./fff" ;
```